# Access Servicstack.net session in validator

Tags: c#, validation, session, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

How can I access a ServiceStack.net session in my validation code?

```
public class UserSettingsValidator : AbstractValidator<UserSettingsRequest>
{
    public UserSettingsValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.UserId)
            .SetValidator(new PositiveIntegerValidator())
            .SetValidator(new UserAccessValidator(session.UserId)); //<-- I need to pass the UserID from the session here
    }
}
```

In the Service Implementation I just do:

```
var session = base.SessionAs<UserSession>();
```

but this does not work for my abstract validator.

Thanks!

Edit: this is version 3.9.71.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are just using the `ValidationFeature` plugin, as most do. If that's the case, then I don't think it is possible. Ultimately the `ValidationFeature` is a plugin which uses a `RequestFilter`.

I wanted to do something similar before too, then realised it wasn't possible.

The `RequestFilter` is run before the `ServiceRunner`. See the [order of operations guide here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations).

What this means to you is your populated request DTO reaches your service, and the validation feature's request filter will try validate your request, before it has even created the `ServiceRunner`.

The `ServiceRunner` is where an instance of your service class becomes active. It is your service class instance that will be injected with your `UserSession` object.

So effectively you can't do any validation that relies on the session at this point.

### Overcomplicated ?:

It is possible to do validation in your service method, and you could create a custom object that would allow you pass the session along with the object you want to validate. (See next section). But I would ask yourself, are you overcomplicating your validation?

For a simple check of the request `UserId` matching the session's `UserId`, presumably you are doing this so the user can only make changes to their own records; Why not check in the service's action method and throw an `Exception`? I am guessing people shouldn't be changing this Id, so it's not so much a validation issue, but more a security exception. *But like I say, maybe your scenario is different.*

```
public class SomeService : Service
{
    public object Post(UserSettingsRequest request) // Match to your own request
    {
        if(request.UserId != Session.UserId)
            throw new Exception("Invalid UserId");
    }
}
```

### Validation in the Service Action:

You should read up on [using Fluent Validators](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation#use-fluentvalidation-everywhere). You can call the custom validator yourself in your service method.

```
// This class allows you to add pass in your session and your object
public class WithSession<T>
{
    public UserSession Session { get; set; }
    public T Object { get; set; }
}

public interface IUserAccessValidator
{
    bool ValidUser(UserSession session);
}

public class UserAccessValidator : IUserAccessValidator
{
    public bool ValidUser(UserSession session)
    {
        // Your validation logic here
        // session.UserId
        return true;
    }
}

public class UserSettingsValidator : AbstractValidator<WithSession<UserSettingsRequest>>
{
    public IUserAccessValidator UserAccessValidator { get; set; }

    public UserSettingsValidator()
    {
        // Notice check now uses .Object to access the object within
        RuleFor(x => x.Object.UserId)
            .SetValidator(new PositiveIntegerValidator());

        // Custom User Access Validator check, passing the session
        RuleFor(x => x.Session).Must(x => UserAccessValidator.ValidUser(x)); 
    }
}
```

Then to actually use the validator in your service:

```
public class SomeService : Service
{
    // Validator with be injected, you need to registered it in the IoC container.
    public IValidator<WithSession<UserSettingsRequest>> { get; set; }

    public object Post(UserSettingsRequest request) // Match to your own request
    {
        // Combine the request with the current session instance
        var requestWithSession = new WithSession<UserSettingsRequest> {
            Session = this.Session,
            Object = request
        };

        // Validate the request
        ValidationResult result = this.Validator.Validate(requestWithSession);
        if(!result.IsValid)
        {
            throw result.ToException();
        }

        // Request is valid
        // ... more logic here
        return result;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. *Note: code is untested*

Comment: wow! Thanks for this good explanation! You are right, it's more of a security problem and I'm going the way to check this directly in the service actions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that after reading from a bunch of people experiencing similar problems, then many hours of playing with several solutions based on the SS4 Cookbook etc, this is a problem that is already solved:

https://forums.servicestack.net/t/blaz-miheljak-355-feb-3-2015/176/2

Implement the IRequiresRequest interface on your validator, and voila.